# How to receive data from web asynchronous and use the result string in the next line of code?

Tags: java, android, http, getjson

I want to get some JSON code from my API. I wish to do something like this in the `OnCreate`:

```
try
{  
   String jsonstr = getSomeThingAndPauseAndroid("http://someplace.com/api/xyz");
   if (!jsonstr.isEmpty()) JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
}
catch { // handle error }
```

But when it happens, Android just go doing stuff and don't wait for the request to complete and response and I get nothing on `jsonstr`.

Is there some way to do that not needing a lot of new class files?

Comment: what's inside getSomeThingAndPauseAndroid?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833977/android-wait-for-volley-response-to-return/23835092

Comment: @Mighter, that's what I am asking to you friends...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to make the request asynchronously and trigger a method on response. This is an example using Google's Volley:

```
 //Start volley:
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);  // this = context


 final String url = "http://someplace.com/api/xyz"";

 // prepare the Request
 JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
     new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() 
     {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {   
             //This is where you setup your UI
             //Remember to dismiss the ProgressDialog
         }
     }, 
     new Response.ErrorListener() 
     {
          @Override
          public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {            
             //Remember to dismiss the ProgressDialog
             Log.d("Error.Response", response);
        }
     }
 );

 // add it to the RequestQueue   
 //Here you should add a ProgressDialog so the user knows to wait
 queue.add(getRequest);
```

Comment: So there's no way of doing that what I want, which I could make on any other OS but not in Android?...

Comment: Yes there is. The code I am giving you does just that but following best practice. The same, by the way, is true on iOS network requests should always be done asynchronously regardless of the platform.

Comment: Where can I download this jar?

Comment: Just simply open your `build.gradle` file in android studio and add in the dependencies: `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.+` that's it!

Comment: does it work for intellijIdea 13? I downloaded the jar file and the ide just went buggy with `Negative Time` log errors and didn't load the `src` package.

Comment: I have no idea. I use android studio and all I have to do is add one line to the build.gradle file. No need to play with jar files.